# CAPL programming -how to manipulate messages from 1 ecu and send it to target

Tags: can-bus, capl, canoe, automotive

I am completely new to CANoe and CAPL. I am trying to implement a man in the middle manipulation between a sender ECU and target ECU.How can i write code in capl to recieving messages from sender ecu in one can channel and change frequency or values of the messages and send them through another channel to the target ECU such that it appears to have come from the sender ecu(how to do the manipulation).Any insight is helpful here.Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
/*@!Encoding:1252*/
includes
{
}

variables
{
    message MessageNameFromECUSender msg; //if the message is defined in dbc
    //message * msg; //if the message isn't defined in dbc, you have to set ID manually
    msTimer msTimerNameFromECUSender;
    qword i = 0; //you will see why
}

//this is thirdFile.cin

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//this code is in ECU Sender Node
variables
{
    #include "thirdFile.cin"
}

on start
{
  setTimer(msTimerNameFromECUSender, 0); //start the timer once configuration started
}

on timer msTimerNameFromECUSender
{
  //if the message have a definition in a dbc database
  msg.SignalName1 = 1;
  msg.SignalName2 = 2;
  
  //if you don't have the message defined intro a dbc but you know the signal layout inside
  msg.byte(0) = 1;
  msg.byte(1) = 2;
  
  output(msg);
  setTimer(msTimerNameFromECUSender, 500); //set timer to send message cyclical once at 500ms
}

on message MessageNameFromECUSender
{
  if(i%2 == 0)
  {
      //recive a message and atribute date to msg variable
      message MessageNameFromECUSender msg_other = this;
      
      //if the message have a definition in a dbc database
      msg_other.SignalName1 = 1;
      msg_other.SignalName2 = 2;
      
      //if you don't have the message defined intro a dbc but you know the signal layout inside
      msg_other.byte(0) = 1;
      msg_other.byte(1) = 2;
      
      msg_other.DLC = 8; //set message length in bytes (aka this messgae have the length of 8 bytes)
      
      if(9223372036854775807 == i)
      {
        i = 0;
      }
      else
      {
        i++;
      }
      output(msg_other); //send message
  }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/*@!Encoding:1252*/
includes
{
    #include "thirdFile.cin"
}

//this is the code in ECU Reciver node, it recive CAN message of ECU sender, modify data and send it back

variables
{
}

on message MessageNameFromECUSender
{
  if(i%2 == 0)
  {
      //recive a message and atribute date to msg variable
      message MessageNameFromECUSender msg_other = this;
      
      //if the message have a definition in a dbc database
      msg_other.SignalName1 = 1;
      msg_other.SignalName2 = 2;
      
      //if you don't have the message defined intro a dbc but you know the signal layout inside
      msg_other.byte(0) = 1;
      msg_other.byte(1) = 2;
      
      msg_other.DLC = 8; //set message length in bytes (aka this messgae have the length of 8 bytes)
      
      cancelTimer(msTimerNameFromECUSender); //stop the timer
      setTimer(msTimerNameFromECUSender, 400); //modify the cycle time
      
      i++;
      output(CAN2.msg_other); //send message on channel CAN2
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**